# alternative ways to method overloading c#

Tags: c#

What is the best way to implement a method that takes different types of class objects?

I have a function:

```
public class WorkerService: IWorkerService
{
    private readonly ISession _session;
    private readonly IPeriodService _periodService;
    private readonly IGService _gService;
    private readonly IIntegrationService _integrationService;

    public OutlookIntegrationWorkerService(...)
    {
        ...
    }

    public enum emunType
    {
        Class1ToExport = 1,
        Class2ToExport = 2,
    }



public void somefunction(Guid id, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken, emunType type)
{
    if(type.Class1ToExport)
    {
        //do work
        somefunction(classObject, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
    }else(type.Class2ToExport){
        //do work
        somefunction(differentClassObject, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
    }



private void somefunction(Class1 classObject, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     //do work
  }

 private void somefunction(Class2 classObject, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
     //do the same work
    }
}
}
```

public void `somefunction(Guid id, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken, emunType type)` is used in multiple differnt classes, I use the enumType to know what kind of object to work with, I dont want to overload the

```
private void somefunction(Class2 classObject, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
         //do the same work
        }
```

sinse it does the same thing

Comment: Well, there's generics, I suppose... Though there is nothing in this question to indicate whether generics are applicable.

Comment: If the classes are derived from the same base class - then having a single method taking a parameter of the base class may work (though depends on what you want to do). Similarly if the classes can both define an Interface for any common functionality the parameter can be the Interface - you would be limited to using the exposed methods & properties of the Interface. But if what the method does is not common between the classes then what @Servy says is correct.

Comment: Why don´t you want to overload the method? What do those two types have in common? If the answer is nothing, then you definitly need two seperate methods to reflect two completely different types.

Comment: I don't want to overload the method again since the logic is exactly the same but with different classes. I wonder if there is a way to make `somefunction(class classObject, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)` into say `somefunction(Object classObject, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)` and in compiletime  `Object` knows what class it is...

Comment: The compiler can only know the types you provide at *compile*-time. Thus whem you provide the type at runtime, there´s no way for the compiler to infer the correct type. So the question still remains: **what do those types have in common?**

Comment: Switching over enum "type" looks like an abstraction issue. if the "someFunction" has the same name, then maybe it should accept a proper implementation of a same interface, just like "IJobCancellationToken". You might want look to a Factory design pattern or pattern matching in recent c# versions

Comment: @Ako if it's exactly the same why discuss overloading? You have only need one method, possibly using generics. What does `somefunction` do? And why use that enum at all?

Comment: @Ako post an actual example of what you want to do. The snippets you posted cause confusion instead of explaining what you want. You could use a generic method. Or you could use pattern matching. Or you could use methods with different names.

Comment: Well the classes must have something in common. Either a common ancestor or a set of properties or methods of coincidental type. In the latter case, define an interface which both of your classes can implement. Then you don't need multiple method overloads, just the interface.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos somefunction creates a jsonObject for two different classes in exactly the same way and instead of dublicating the code I thought maybe there is a way to tell the function what type of class is injected

Comment: the enum is to tell if its say class1 or class2

Comment: Conversion errors? Pretty sure that's because whatever you are trying to do in the method does not reflect how you would work with generics, again as other said what does `somefunction` do, post your code for that method it is unclear.

Comment: `somefunction` creates an object with the class object that was used when the function is called , and forwards it to anohter function which is not important really, the issue is not there instead I only want to know if there is another way instead of method overloading

Comment: We already gave you options, and that `Conversion Errors` is obviously something wrong within that method. How do you expect us to help you when you provide no concrete example code snippets.

Comment: thanks for the help, I'll read more on Generics. the enum is just there so I know what kind of class object to work with, the classes are different and I fetch them from different tables from 5 other diffent classes when they are saved, I probalby get conversion errors sinse the classes that I want to work with don't implement generics, I didn't upload the whole code becouse it's simply too long

Comment: only thing I wanted was information but people would rather play keyboard warriors and downvote instead of actually helping... But thanks for the rest for the helpfull comments!

Comment: @Ako: You still could do with providing more code. I'm not sure what you are doing with `classObject` in your `someFunction`but the only possibilities I can think of are a) they share a common interface or base class which allows you to call the same methods/properties on the different types b) You don't call any methods or properties on the object (could still be using reflection or similar) c) Your two bits of code may look the same but in fact aren't since they operate on different objects. How you handle it best depends on what case we are in so having code for those methods would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:** I'd use a [strategy pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern) with an [abstract factory](https://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern) to create the strategies.

**Detail:** Create an Interface `IClassExportStrategy` containing this method:

```
   void Export(IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

This interface defines what all the strategies will *do*.

For each `ClassX` that you want to export, create a `ClassXExportStrategy` class, which takes an instance of `ClassX` in the constructor, and implements the interface. (These classes are the *strategies*.)

Now create a class `ClassExportStrategyAbstractFactory`. It has one method:

```
public IClassExportStrategy GetClassExportStrategy(object @object)
{
    if(@object is class1)
    {
        return new Class1ExportStrategy(@object as Class1);
    }

    // repeat for other classes...

    // Finally:
    throw new NotImplementedExcepton(@object.GetType().FullName);
}
```

Notice how this means you don't need the enum any more.

To use it, simply call the abstract factory's `GetClassExportStrategy` passing the instance of the class you want exported (which will return you the relevant strategy), then call the `Export` method on that.

Comment: Nice this works! and explains much better what I wanted to do in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you can get the Type of the object and work with that:

```
public void somefunction(Guid id, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken, Object classObject)
{
    if(object is class1)
    {
        //do work
        somefunction(classObject, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
    }else if(object is class2){
        //do work
        differentfunction(classObject, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
    }
}
```

It is not most elegant, then I would use Generics as Amy proposed

Comment: the functions do the same work and i don't want to dublicate the work

Comment: When you have only one function why your objects would not comply to the same interface and you pass the interface object in the function?

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is that declare WorkerService as generic and  abstract, that somefunction is generic abstract method, and in derived type pass Class1 or Class2 as generic value like this:

```
public abstract class WorkerService<T> : IWorkerService where T : class
{
    private readonly ISession _session;
    private readonly IPeriodService _periodService;
    private readonly IGService _gService;
    private readonly IIntegrationService _integrationService;

    public OutlookIntegrationWorkerService(...)
    {
        ...
    }

    public enum emunType
    {
        Class1ToExport = 1,
        Class2ToExport = 2,
    }

    protected abstract void somefunction<T>(Guid id, IJobCancellationToken 
    cancellationToken);
}

public class WorkerService_Class1 : WorkerService<Class1>
{
    protected override void somefunction<T>(Guid id, IJobCancellationToken 
    cancellationToken)
    {
        //do work
    }


}
public class WorkerService_Class2 : WorkerService<Class2>
{
    protected override void somefunction<T>(Guid id, IJobCancellationToken 
   cancellationToken)
    {
        //do work
    }
}
```

Comment: did not test this one yet, Decide to go with @Richardissimo suggestion. Thanks for the help!